# Word for a person who eats meat but not fish

Tags: choix-de-mot

Is there a specific word or expression for a person who eats meat but not fish or seafood in general? Can one use the term "carnetarian" in French?

Comment: *Carniste*, terme utilisé par les anti-spécistes est plutôt péjoratif et je ne pense pas que quelqu'un qui ne mange que de la viande l'emploierait pour lui-même, encore moins *viandard* et *viandale*.  J'ai déjà rencontré  *pesco-végétarien* (poisson et végétaux), *pollo-végétarien* (végétaux et poulet) mais jamais rencontré  *carno-végétarien* ni *carnétarien*, mais c'est très bien de néologiser...

Comment: @none thank you very much for this comment. But why a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @None ok! Still a vey useful comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Carniste*** is a word used by antispeciesists in a negative way and I doubt any meat lover/eater would use it for themselves.

> Adepte du carnisme, idéologie justifiant la consommation de viandes, donc l'élevage et les abattoirs, alors même que cette consommation ne constitue pas une nécessité. ([*Cordial*](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/carniste.php))

The original meaning of ***viandard*** is:

> Chasseur (tueur) pour qui seule compte la chasse, la quantité de viande abattue, rapportée et, quelquefois, vendue ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/viande))

but I've heard it used to qualify  someone who loves eating meat. One of the definitions given in the [*Dictionnaire de la zone*](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/viandard):

> 2. Qui aime manger de la viande.

But saying someone is a *viandard* doesn't imply they never eat fish. And it is derogatory.

The word ***viandale*** is also derogatory and supposedly coined by journalist and animal rights activist Aymeric Caron.

> Je parle ici de ceux que j’appelle les « viandales ». Il y a quelque chose d’indécent, de vulgaire à avoir des gens qui s’empiffrent d’un gros bout de viande au mépris total de ce que veut vraiment dire ce bout de viande, de là d’où il vient, de ce qu’a pu endurer l’animal…  (Aymeric Caron in an interview for the periodical [*We demain*](https://www.wedemain.fr/ralentir/aymeric-caron-j-ai-honte-d-appartenir-a-cette-humanite_a3718-html/))

I've recently come across *pesco-végétarien* and *pollo-végétarien*<sup>1</sup>, but I've never met ***carno-végétarien***.
I've never come across the word ***carnetarien*** either but it would indeed be logical to have *carnetarien* along *pescetarien* and *végétarien*. Et les néologismes font vivre la langue !

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I think the words "pollotarian" and  "pescetarian" were used before in English.</sub>

Comment: Viandard + Vandale → Viandale ?

Comment: @Personne C'est comme ça que je le comprends...